# Are all main lines and variations of chess openings necessarily SOUND?

Tags: opening, theory

Are all main lines and variations of chess openings necessarily SOUND?.

I mean since we can't know all possible games, unique games, which are so large, about 10⁴⁰, how can I be sure that all "book", "theory" openings are SOUND?

I mean that, may be, some "book" openings may be UNSOUND?

Strong CHESS Engines may, to a limit, can examine all "book", "theory" chess openings.

Sound chess openings should lead to a decisive, not drawish, games. If a white opening, should lead to white win. If a black defence, should lead to black win.

Sound book, theory white opening should lead to white win, provided that no inaccuracy, mistake or blunder, from the white. And the same runs for the black defence. Note that possible games are very large, approximately 10⁴⁰ unique games.

I suggest that this is why Super Grandmasters, stopped at 2850 Elo, no even the world champion could beat any strong chess engine.

Of course we exclude inaccuracies, mistakes, and blunders.

Comment: If your definition is "Sound chess openings should lead to a decisive games. If a white opening, should lead to white win. If a black defence, should lead to black win." then there are no sound openings at all.

Comment: @IanBush I said "under one condition: no mistake,  no blunder". I am so clear.

Comment: Still the same answer, I had assumed that condition already,. There isn't a (known) forced win in chess, which is what you are essentially asking.

Comment: @IanBush I don't agree with you, Sound book, theory white opening should lead to white win, provided that no mistake or blunder, from the white. And the same runs for the black defence. Note that possible games are very large, approximately 10⁴⁰ unique games.

Comment: "_Sound book, theory white opening should lead to white win, provided that no inaccuracy, mistake or blunder, from the white. And the same runs for the black defence._" Is this your personal definition?  (that's fine if it is, just trying to determine where this definition comes from)

Comment: @SecretAgentMan my understanding is according to LOGIC. You can refute my understanding in an answer post.

Comment: @salah There is no need to use all caps here. I'm not refuting anything. I found your question interesting and wanted to know more before I contemplate an answer.

Comment: *Are all main lines and variations of chess openings necessarily sound?*   Stockfish might argue that the main line of the Grob is unsound (1. g4).

Comment: @SecretAgentMan could you put your what you see in an answer post?

Answer (score 1):

> Sound book, theory white opening should lead to white win, provided that no inaccuracy, mistake or blunder, from the white. And the same runs for the black defence

> Are all main lines and variations of chess openings necessarily SOUND?

Using your incorrect definition of "sound" the simple answer is "**No**". There are no "sound" openings according to your definition. There are no openings which give either white or black a forced win with best play by both sides.

Comment: what is the definition of Sound Opening according to you?, Is it "Sound Opening" what is in the book?, Of the Opening Theory?

Comment: @salah "Sound" is the exact opposite of what you said - neither side gets a decisive advantage with best play. By that definition openings like the Grob and the Bongcloud are borderline unsound if not outright unsound.

Comment: At its simplest sound means "not losing". It generally means a bit more such as "at least equal" and then rapidly gets subjective. But what it does *not* mean is "winning"